# Appium iOS iOSNsPredicate evaluates to multiple elements how to specify one of them?

Tags: appium-ios

Say I have following mobile element in Appium UI test:

```
@iOSXCUITFindBy(iOSNsPredicate = "name = 'Enter Address'")
private MobileElement enterAddress;
```

in case the iOSNsPredicate evaluates to multiple elements, how can I apply an index to it, so that the scripts will click a specific mobile element?

by default it only click the first one in the result list, but sometimes it is not the correct one. So I want to know if anyway we can use to click one other than the first one?
Thanks.

[image: ue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using iOSClassChain instead of iOSNsPredicate. For example

```
**/XCUIElementTypeAny[`name == "Enter Address"`][2]
```

would select the second element with that same name, like your question suggests. Index starts at 1.

More details in documentation [Class Chain Queries Construction Rules](https://github.com/facebookarchive/WebDriverAgent/wiki/Class-Chain-Queries-Construction-Rules)